# How do I print out the contents of my settings in a django shell?

Tags: python, django

When I run `python manage.py shell`, I can print out the python path

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
```

What should I type to introspect all my django settings ?

Comment: do you mean your settings.py file?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

```
from django.conf import settings
dir(settings)
```

and then choose attribute from what `dir(settings)` have shown you to say:

```
settings.name
```

where `name` is the attribute that is of your interest

Alternatively:

```
settings.__dict__
```

prints all the settings. But it prints also the module standard attributes, which may somewhat clutter the output.

Comment: import settings will not work. try from django.conf import settings as vinod suggested.

Comment: `settings` is a module, not a class. So `settings.__dict__` is not really useful.

Comment: How do you do from the settings.py file itself? I guess importing settings from settings wouldn't end well.

Answer (score 88):

I know that this is an old question, but with current versions of django (1.6+), you can accomplish this from the command line the following way:

```
python manage.py diffsettings --all
```

The result will show all of the settings including the defautls (denoted by ### in front of the settings name).

Comment: there is no django 2.7+ (yet). `diffsettings` exists in >=1.4. `--all` was added in 1.6. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#diffsettings

Comment: @Florian  Thank's for noticing the oversight.  I've updated my answer to fix that.

Comment: This is the proper answer. Viewing settings without modifying the code would be the better choice.

Answer (score 20):

In case a newbie stumbles upon this question wanting to be spoon fed the way to print out the values for all settings:

```
def show_settings():
    from django.conf import settings
    for name in dir(settings):
        print(name, getattr(settings, name))
```

Answer (score 15):

To show all django settings (including default settings not specified in your local settings file):

```
from django.conf import settings
dir(settings)
```

Answer (score 3):

In your shell, you can call Django's built-in [diffsettings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#diffsettings):

```
from django.core.management.commands import diffsettings

output = diffsettings.Command().handle(default=None, output="hash", all=False)
```