# Azure build modifies host in mongo_client.py to localhost

Tags: python, django, mongodb, azure, deployment

I have written a django application with mongodb as backend, created models and used DJONGO to setup the ORM, below is my settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'conversations',
        'HOST':'mongodb+srv://userName:password@clusterx-abcde.mongodb.net/dbName?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
        'USER':'userName',
        'PASSWORD':'password'
    }
}
```

I had to end up modifying host from localhost to **'mongodb+srv://userName:password@clusterx-abcde.mongodb.net/dbName?retryWrites=true&w=majority'** in mongo_clients.py(pymongo package).

**[Django cant connect to mongoDB atlas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60331228/django-cant-connect-to-mongodb-atlas/60338251#60338251)**
**https://github.com/nesdis/djongo/issues/132**

Above are the links I referred to, to change host on mongo_clients.py

This application works fine on my local machine, once I host it on azure, during the build azure is modifying the **mongo_clients.py** and changing the host to localhost making my application not work as expected.

```
class MongoClient(common.BaseObject):
    """
    A client-side representation of a MongoDB cluster.

    Instances can represent either a standalone MongoDB server, a replica
    set, or a sharded cluster. Instances of this class are responsible for
    maintaining up-to-date state of the cluster, and possibly cache
    resources related to this, including background threads for monitoring,
    and connection pools.
    """
    HOST = 'mongodb+srv://userName:password@clusterx-abcde.mongodb.net/dbName?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
    PORT = 27017
    # Define order to retrieve options from ClientOptions for __repr__.
    # No host/port; these are retrieved from TopologySettings.
    _constructor_args = ('document_class', 'tz_aware', 'connect')
```

Is there anyway to have azure ignore these changes I made on mongo_client.py, it's part of pymongo package

Comment: Hacking the library code is not the answer. Azure isn't modifying anything, it is just pulling down the latest library which is entirely standard for any build process.

Comment: Yes, but how do fix this ? is this a dead-end ? there should be someway right ?

Comment: Have you tried `pip install dnspython` as suggested in the links?

Comment: yes, I did, that didn't help either